# meaning of 楽{たの}しむ, the verb being used intransitively

Tags: words, meaning

I read in the [Asahi Shimbun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asahi_Shimbun) the following [article's headline](http://www.asahi.com/articles/ASJ4855P7J48PLZB01D.html?iref=comtop_6_01) (*furigana* are mine) :

> 神様{かみさま}も楽{たの}しむ？　桜{さくら}の新{しん}品種{ひんしゅ}、京都{きょうと}で発見{はっけん}　北野天満宮{きたのてんまんぐう}
>
> my translation :
>
> Do the gods enjoy themselves ? A new variety of cherry tree discovered in Kyōto ([Kitano Tenman-gū](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kitano_Tenman-g%C5%AB))

I understand the meaning of 楽{たの}しむ used transitively; e.g. ([source](http://nihongo.monash.edu/cgi-bin/wwwjdic?1Q%B3%DA%A4%B7%A4%E0_1_)) :

> 私{わたくし}は水泳{すいえい}を楽{たの}しんだ。
>
> I enjoyed swimming.

But what about 楽{たの}しむ used intransitively ? What's the exact meaning of "神様{かみさま}も楽{たの}しむ？" ? Is it :

- the gods are in a good mood ?
- the gods are amusing themselves ?
- the gods want to make a joke ?

Any help would be appreciated !

Comment: Bear in mind that, in the context of Japan, 神様{かみさま} likely refers to the Japanese _kami_ (i.e. plural) and not to the Christian God (i.e. singular).

Comment: @EiríkrÚtlendi : of course, you're right. I have fixed my translation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the 神様も楽しむ in the headline means:

> 神様も**桜を**楽しむ(のか)？ -- The gods enjoy cherry blossoms, too?
>   or
>   神様も**桜を見て**楽しむ(のか)？ -- The gods enjoy seeing cherry blossoms, too?

with 桜を(見て) being left out.

---

I believe 楽しむ can be used intransitively, as in:

> テレビを見て楽しみました。 (←more natural than テレビを見ることを楽しみました。)
>   ゲームをして楽しみました。
>   遊園地に行って、一日中、思いっきり楽しみました。

Comment: Thank you very much : your examples are interesting. Thanks too for correcting the reading of 新品種.